# issue with admin users collection

Tags: magento

I am having basic knowledge of Magento. I am customizing "create new order" module in admin. I want to show the list of admin users expect customers when admin generates new order. I am customizing the file -

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Customer/Grid.php
```

In `_prepareCollection()` function  -

`"$collection = Mage::getModel("permissions/users")->getCollection();"`

But returns nothing when I print the `$collection` object. I have also tried by using custom query -

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM admin_user';            
$collection = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

But it cannot create the collection object.
Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel("admin/roles_user_collection")` returns the expected collection object.

Comment: If the above answer is correct, please accept the answer by click the tick mark bellow to the reputation point which will be useful to others.

Comment: It requires 20 hours after posting the answer and to accept it.